# How to pronounce "Er"?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is "er" sometimes pronounced /e/ as in:

> Er schläft

and sometimes pronounced /eːɐ/ as in:

> Er ist gelb.

Comment: They are not pronounced differently.

Comment: The first pronounciation seems wrong. The "r" is said, not always clearly, but it is not completely ommited.

Comment: What gives you the idea that they are?

Comment: @Emanuel "Rosetta Stone"

Comment: Then, the same phenomenon applies as described in the other answer... however, I would say that most people would at least pronounce a hint of an "a". it might be beyond what a student can hear, though or maybe we just hear it because we want to.

Comment: @Meysam I tried *Rosetta Stone* to learn another language and wouldn’t recommend to pay attention to subtle nuances in pronunciation like this. It really depends on the speaker and their pronunciation is also sometimes a little exaggerated.

Answer (score 3):

The word "Er" is pronounced the same way in both cases.

Comment: Half-right. Both cases are pronounced the same, but the letter "R" is pronounced differently, with a weak "e" and a strong "r" (I can't write IPA).

Comment: Confusingly, in standard German pronunciation, the r in Er (or at the end of most other words) is not pronounced like the letter itself, but as a schwa /ɐ/.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit different. The alphabet pronunciation emphasizes more the "r"-sound. But in general there's no big difference. However, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In some dialects or in colloquial German there are cases when *er* has different pronunciations, but not in "high German". There's actually no rule for that and you are fine pronouncing *er* as /eːɐ/ all the time.

One case where *er* **could** be pronounced differently is the following

> A: Hat er das wirklich gesagt??
>   B: Ja, hat er.

In both cases, *hat er* could be pronounced like "*hatä*" or "*hatär*", but also like *hat /eːɐ/*.

Still, as I said, there's no rule, but from my feeling, the difference is that in one case (the high German pronunciation) both words are pronounced separately (*hat er*), while in the other case, both words are more or less pronounced like one word (*hater*, *gehter*, *stehter*, *liegter*, *fragter*).